# How can we use $(this) and option selected

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

`$('#selectList :selected').text()`  is known syntax

i have to fetch the value for the same from `$(this)` instead of `$('#selected')`

something like this

`$(this :selected').text()` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$() can take two arguments:

```
$(selector, context)
```

so it may be possible to use

```
$(':selected', this).text();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use either

```
$(':selected', this).text();
```

or

```
$(this).find(':selected').text();
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can also do something like this:

$(this).find(":selected").text();